# Java regular expression with Matching text and special charachter

Tags: java, string, substring

Hi I am new to java regex. I have the below string

`String s = " "KBC_2022-12-20-2004_IDEAL333_MASTER333_2022-12-20-1804_SUCCESS";`

I wanted to only Print "333" which is appended with MASTER . The output should be 333.
Can someone help me writing the regex for this . Basically the code should print the value between "MASTER" and the next "_". here its 333 but the value might be of any number of character not limit to length 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex: `(?<=MASTER)[0-9]+(?=\_)`.

We are looking for everything between `MASTER` and `_`:

- **lookbehind**: everything that goes after `MASTER`: `(?<=MASTER)`
- **lookahead**: everything that goes before `_`: `(?=\_)`

Try on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yVFbEp/1)

Comment: String time = "Thu Dec 22 01:12:22 UTC 2022";
I used the same logic here to fetch the HH:MM:SS (01:12:22) here but its not working . Is the regex different ? if it is what is the regex ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do `MASTER(\\d+)_`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("MASTER(\\d+)_");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" KBC_2022-12-20-2004_IDEAL333_MASTER333_2022-12-20-1804_SUCCESS");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // 333
}
m = p.matcher(" KBC_2022-12-20-2004_IDEAL333_MASTER123_2022-12-20-1804_SUCCESS");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // 123
}
```